# Powershell script completely removing user profile, user's folder, and user's registry key for dormant accounts

Tags: windows-10, powershell, user-profiles, users

I'm trying to create a Powershell script that removes from a Windows computer a user's profile, a user's folder in "C:\Users", and a user's registry key in "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" - All for any user whose profile is dormant beyond 90 days, disregarding specific administrator or service accounts.

The reason I need all three is because I want to make sure this script removes dormant profiles that include both local accounts as well as domain accounts from a computer.

Note: I am trying not to use Group Policy to accomplish what I'm doing here, just Powershell.

Here is the code I have so far that isn't working:

```
Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_UserProfile | 
Where-Object {(!$_.Special) -and ($_.LastUseTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)) -and ($_.SID -notmatch '-500$')} | 
Remove-CimInstance -WhatIf

$profiledirectory="C:\Users\"
Get-ChildItem -Path $profiledirectory | Where-Object {$_.LastAccessTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90) -and ($_.FullName -notmatch 'Administrator|Public|LocalAdmin') }
    ForEach-Object{
        Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList' |
            ForEach-Object{
            $profilepath=$_.GetValue('ProfileImagePath')    
            if($profilepath -notmatch 'administrator|NetworkService|Localservice|systemprofile|LocalAdmin'){
                Write-Host "Removing item: $profilepath" -ForegroundColor green
                Remove-Item $_.PSPath -Whatif
                Remove-Item $profilepath -Recurse -Force -Whatif
            }else{
                Write-Host "Skipping item:$profilepath" -Fore blue -Back white
            }
        }
    }
```

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Which parts aren't working and in what manner? Is it finding the wrong profiles, or failing to delete them, or something else?

Comment: Yes, please give us more information on what in this script is failing.

Comment: I commend to your attention the WMI class `Win32_UserProfile` and its `.Delete()` method.

Comment: Hi all - Sorry I've been away for a few days, but today I had the chance to follow back up on this. So when I run the script, it seems the Remove-CimInstance isn't working because the profiles are still present at the login screen, in Computer Management, and in Settings > Accounts > Family and Other Users.

Comment: The second part of the script that deals with removing directories in C:\Users\ and in the registry (ProfileList) seems to work. When I look in both locations, the reference to the profiles have been removed. But because I am still able to see the profiles listed at the login screen, when I log back into these profiles the profile directory in C:\Users\ and the registry entry in ProfileList both get recreated as if it's the first time the profile is being logged into on that machine. So I still need to figure out why Remove-CimInstance isn't removing a standard user in this case.

Comment: @Jeff Can you provide an example of using the .Delete() method in my scenario? Thank you!

Comment: Because of certain security decisions on my organization's network, we have not yet migrated from WMI to CIM, so I'm not entirely confident in my ability to write a CIM-compatible example. However, I have a script that we routinely use that does a `Get-WMIObject ...` against the remote computer, returning a `Win32_UserProfile` object, and then we simply call that object's `.Delete()` method to delete the user profile from the remote computer, e.g., `$userprofile.Delete()`. My understanding is that CIM objects are deserialized, and you'd thus have to call `Invoke-CIMMethod`.

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite it as:

```
delprof2 /d:60
```

The [delprof2](https://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/) tool is a standalone `.exe` download.

Comment: Would you say that it's not possible to accomplish what I'm trying to do solely through Powershell, or just that it's easier to use delprof2? Thanks!

Comment: Everything that can be done in Windows is possible to do through PowerShell (even things that don't have cmdlets can be reached through .NET's P/Invoke), but it's _a lot_ easier to just use an existing tool if it works.

Comment: @KoreyMendes - Are you willing to go through the dozens of corner cases and write every step of the process yourself? The only way I would suggest doing that is if you literally cannot run the tool.

Comment: It might be easier to use an existing tool. But if you cannot access the source code it might also have some risks. Despite that you won't learn how to do it yourself.