# Removing User Account through Registry using .BAT

Tags: command-line, batch-file, windows-registry

I am not the best at scripting but do know enough to write and modify to do what I want.

This is an Enterprise environment and after adding a computer to the domain, we would like to delete the user profile that was used before it was put on the domain: "Image"

Once the computer is on our Domain, we run a bunch of scripts. One script deletes the "Image" user account and the profile folder from the C: Drive but the user account still remains in Registry under Profile List.

Trying to find a command that can be added to our .BAT script that will delete the parent folder (S-1-5-21...) using the ProfileImagePath key ONLY if the DataItemName is: `C:\Users\Image`

Plain and Simple: `.BAT` script needed to delete parent folder (S-1-5-21...) from the location (Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList) using the DataItemName (C:\Users\Image)

Comment: Why aren't you using the Powershell cmdlet `Remove-LocalUser`?

Comment: Also this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62656577/remove-local-user-and-data-from-windows-10-using-powershell

Comment: And this post: https://superuser.com/questions/1728242/powershell-script-completely-removing-user-profile-users-folder-and-users-re

Comment: And this one too: https://superuser.com/questions/1569479/delete-local-accounts-with-powershell-script

Comment: We are using a .bat to delete the user account "Image" and its user folder but this will not delete the key in Registry. Using Remove-LocalUser in Powershell does the same thing, removes account and folder but not the registry part

Comment: Look at https://superuser.com/questions/1569479/delete-local-accounts-with-powershell-script , which *shows how to remove the Registry entry*.

Comment: Found something that actually worked:  Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object { $_.LocalPath.split('\')[-1] -eq 'image' } | Remove-CimInstance.          Thank you all for reaching out. I should have stated that several of the links that were posted were ones that I have already found when searching on Google and Bing as I have been looking and researching for a month.